# Run query between PostGIS layer and Shapefile layer with DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, dbmanager

Is it possible to use the DB Manager in QGIS (I am using version 3.4) to run a SQL query between a project layer (e.g. shapefile) and a PostGIS layer?

For example, I have a polygon shapefile in my QGIS project in the layers panel and I want to select all point features (saved in a PostGIS database but not loaded in my layers panel) that are within the shapefile polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it via a virtual layer. Go to the `Layer` menu, `add layer / add-edit virtual layer`. You can then use all your layers (Shapefile, db etc) in a query.
The layers must be in the table of content, and the output will be a new virtual layer.

Ex: `a` is a Shapefile, `b` is a PostGIS layer:

```
select a.*
from a,b
where st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
```